# Blockchain with Vscode

Tags: solidity, blockchain, truffle

TextFieldValue(text='I switch my career from Laravel dev to Blockchain, I want to know how to setup blockchain environment on your visual studio code. What do i need to install and start over?

I was using remix online to write smart contract but the platform doesn't seem interesting, I need someone to help me on how to configure my vscode to write smart contract offline like normal software packages. Do i need a framework for it?', selection=TextRange(413, 413), composition=null)

TextFieldValue(text='', selection=TextRange(0, 0), composition=null)

Answer (score 0):

Vscode itself is not a blockchain development framework at all but just a text editor with a bunch of features; Consider googling hardhat/ganache/foundry for your requirements.

Comment: Alright. Can i run those framework on Vscode?

Answer (score 0):

In order to start with developing smart contracts on vscode, install solidity and remix extensions on vscode.
Create a new project folder 
cd into the folder and run,
1 ) npm init
2 ) npx hardhat

This will install hardhat as dependency.
Inside hardhat config you can set up the preferred network for deploying the contract or you can run 'npx hardhat node' which will run on local network and creates few addresses to play around with. You can also use one of these addresses to connect with metamask.